How to change the Text color of ContentPresenter based on the control state in .Net MAUI
My question is an extension to this question where I want to change the text color based on the state of the radio button. I want it white if checked and black if unchecked.
Details:
I am using a custom styled Radio Button in my application following Redefine RadioButton appearance where it creates ControlTemplate to customize the appearance and uses ContentPresenter for displaying text/content.
I modified it to the shape I want, but unable to change the Text color based on the whether the radio button is checked or not.
Below is my code.
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
    <Border x:Name="RadioBorder1"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 3"
            BackgroundColor="#F3F2F1"
            HeightRequest="30"
            WidthRequest="120">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="MediumPurple" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="MediumPurple" />
                            <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                            <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid Margin="4" WidthRequest="120">
            <Grid WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="30">
                <RoundRectangle />
                <RoundRectangle x:Name="check" />
            </Grid>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="5,1,1,1" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>

<!--Radio Buttons--> 
<Label Text="What's your favorite color?" />
<VerticalStackLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="colors">
    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="3,0,0,0">
        <RadioButton Content="Red" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" />
        <RadioButton Content="Green" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" />
        <RadioButton Content="Blue" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <RadioButton Content="Enable" />
        <RadioButton Content="Disable" />
        <RadioButton Content="Other" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <RadioButton Content="Working" />
        <RadioButton Content="Turbo Power" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</VerticalStackLayout>

I tried changing the text color on CheckedChanged event, but that didn't help.
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)

{
RadioButton? button = sender as RadioButton;
if ((button?.IsChecked ?? false) == true)
{
    val = button?.Content?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    //button.TextColor = Colors.White;
}

}
This is what I have now and I am trying to change the text color to white for the selected item.
Thanks for your help.

May I ask what .NET version and what platform you are using?

I am using .net8.0 and I am trying it on android emulator  pixel 5 - API 34:5554

You could use Relative Bindings and Binding value converters to solve it.
What I am going to do is to bind the Label's TextColor property to the RadioButton's IsChecked property,
<Label Text="Cat"
       TextColor="{Binding IsChecked,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}},Converter={StaticResource isCheckedConverter}}"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="End" />

So, we need a value converter to convert IsChecked property value
(True/False) to the Label TextColor value.  We create a new Class called IsCheckedConverter.cs,
public class IsCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool a = (bool)value;
        if (a)
        {
            return Colors.White;
        }
        else {
            return Colors.Black;           
        }         
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

Don't forget to put it in the ContentPage.Resources
<ContentPage.Resources>
    ......

    <local:IsCheckedConverter x:Key="isCheckedConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>


Thank you. Using Relative Bindings and Binding value converters  is the trick.. Here is the C# equivalent code that I used `var isCheckedConverter = new IsCheckedConverter();
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
radioButton.Value = "Yes";
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Yes";
label.SetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty, new Binding("IsChecked", source: radioButton, converter: isCheckedConverter));
radioButton.Content = label;`

Glad it helps! Happy coding!
